# Debub .bbl for missing right brace

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, errors

I have a long .bbl which is generating an error when compiling with LaTeX.

The error message is

```
ERROR: Paragraph ended before \name was complete.

--- TeX said ---
<to be read again> 
                   \par 
l.1166 

--- HELP ---
A blank line occurred in a command argument that shouldn't contain
one. You probably forgot the right brace at the end of an argument.
```

`l.1166` refers to the last line of my .bbl file.

```
...
1161      \endverb
1162    \endentry
1163  \endsortlist
1164 \endrefsection
1165 \endinput
1166
```

But how can I easily identify the problematic bibliographic entry without try to remove them one at a time and rerun LaTeX each time?

Comment: In Emacs, you could use `M-x check-parens` on your `.bib` file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another plug for [Emacs](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/) is

```
M-x check-parens
```

which does as it says: checks to make sure all your parentheses, braces, and square brackets have a matching partner.  (Note that it can become confused by opening or closing braces that have been commented out.)